# TableView inside cell?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, uitableview, nested

There are many apps(especially sns apps) which show a nested list.

e.g.) pinterest, path.

Are there standard practices of making nested list in iOS(or android)?

1. sections as outer list, rows as inner list
2. tableview as outer list, tableview inside a cell as inner list.
3. something else..

Comment: Nested tableViews sounds like a reign of trouble - even without even trying it myself, I would definitely recommend against it.

Comment: I agree.  `UITableView`s and `UITableViewCell`s have so many build in gesture recognizers and then like that interaction with such a thing could be a nightmare.  Theres definitely a more lightweight solution to your problem.

Comment: In worse case you can try to implement such control from scratch and then you can make it work both on iOS and Android platforms... But I also think that it will better to use other solutions.